# Application specific password required when sending mail in android through gmail smtp

Tags: java, android, email

Hi i am sending email from my android app in background here is my code to send mail:

```
    static {   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abc@xyz.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "abc@def.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      properties.setProperty("mail.user", "abc@xyz.com");
      properties.setProperty("mail.password", "xyz");
      properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
         try {
             t.connect(host, "abc@xyz.com", "xyz");
             t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
         } finally {
             t.close();
         }
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

i also added JSSEProvider class as security provider when i try to send email i got following error in debug trace:  534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
534 5.7.9 http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833 fr7sm14810157pdb.79 - gsmtp
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException my username ans password are correct still i am getting same exception, please help me!